# Flash audio problem; redirecting to Pulse?

Tags: sound, xubuntu, flash, pulseaudio, alsa

I am having a problem where the sound on flash objects other than YouTube videos are giving a strange distortion. It has a high pitched pulse sound every second or less that resembles skips on a record. I have no idea what the problem is or how to fix it. Does anyone have an idea what I could do to fix this?

I am running Xubuntu 11.10. I think I might have redirected everything to pulse using a config file but I cannot seem to find it anywhere. It used the lines 'type pulse' in it. If  anyone knows what I am talking about and how to find that file or whether or not it has any relevance I would greatly appreciate it.

***EDIT:** I solved it. The problem was that I needed to update the flash plugin in Chrome and Chromium manually.*

Comment: Rather than editing your question we'd like to encourage you to **answer** your own questions with details on how you solved your problem.

Answer (score 2):

I solved it. The problem was that I needed to update the flash plugin in **Chrome** and **Chromium** manually. I went to http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/ and downloaded the "*.tar.gz for other Linux*" option and copied the **.so** file into the plugins directory for all of my browsers.